# Is there a way to get the result of on a .then and pass it as string or something like that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

so I got this code (don’t laugh at me, I’m pretty new on this, maybe this is something simple but I can’t figure it out)

```
// Get latidude & longitude from address.
  Geocode.fromAddress({ location }).then(finalLocation => {
    const mylocation = finalLocation.results[0].geometry.location;
    console.log(mylocation);
  });
```

This returns in the sonsole the next line **{lat: 42.xxxxx, lng: -72.xxxx}** but I would like to use it on my component to make a dynamic map on every event I post.

I would like that result to load here

```
<GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }}
          defaultCenter={{lat: 42.xxxxx, lng: -72.xxxx}}
          defaultZoom={13}
        >
          <Location lat={40.xxxx} lng={-73.xxxx} />
        </GoogleMapReact>
```

Below the full code of the component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  deleteEvent,
  getEvents
} from "../../actions/event";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

const pointerCard = require("../../resources/images/contact-pointer.jpg");

Geocode.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

const Location = () => (
  <Row className="block-on-map">
    <Col>
      <img src={pointerCard} alt="Dorothy Ophals Business Card" />
    </Col>
  </Row>
);

const FullEvent = ({
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  getEvents,
  event: {
    _id,
    eventphoto,
    title,
    when,
    location,
    description,
    name,
    avatar,
    user,
    likes,
    comments,
    date
  }
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, [getEvents]);

  // Get latidude & longitude from address.
  Geocode.fromAddress({ location }).then(finalLocation => {
    const mylocation = finalLocation.results[0].geometry.location;
    console.log(mylocation);
    return this.setState({
      ceneter: finalLocation.mylocation
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="post-container">
      <div className="full-post-image">
        <img
          src={`https://uploads.dorothyophals.com/${eventphoto}`}
          alt={title}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="full-post-intro">
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }}
          defaultCenter={ceneter}
          defaultZoom={13}
        >
          <Location lat={40.7263441} lng={-73.4364847} />
        </GoogleMapReact>
        <div className="user-in-posts">
          <Row>
            <Col lg="4">
              <div className="posts-avatar">
                <Link to={`/profile/${user}`}>
                  <img src={avatar} alt={name} style={{ width: "100%" }} />
                </Link>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col lg="8">
              <div className="posts-data">
                <p>Event By</p>
                <h5>
                  <Link to={`/profile/${user}`}>{name}</Link>
                </h5>
                <small className="text-muted">
                  <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{date}</Moment>
                </small>
                <div className="full-post-interaction">
                  <button
                    onClick={e => addLike(_id, window.location.reload(false))}
                    type="button"
                    className="post-like"
                  >
                    <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
                    <span className="counts">{likes.length}</span>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={e =>
                      removeLike(_id, window.location.reload(false))
                    }
                    type="button"
                    className="post-like"
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-heart-broken"></i>
                  </button>
                  <i className="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
                  {comments.length > 0 && (
                    <span className="counts">{comments.length}</span>
                  )}
                </div>
                <Link to="/posts" className="dashboard-goback">
                  Back to Events
                </Link>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
        <div className="card-title">{title}</div>

        <div className="card-text">
          <div className="event-info">
            <div className="info-blocks">
              <i
                className="fas fa-location-arrow"
                style={{ float: "left" }}
              ></i>
              <h5 style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: 10 }}>{location}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="info-blocks">
              <i
                className="far fa-calendar-alt"
                style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: 30 }}
              ></i>
              <h5 style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: 10 }}>
                <Moment format="MMMM DD, YYYY | hh:mm A">{when}</Moment>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="full-post-body">
            <h3>What is the event about</h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

FullEvent.propTypes = {
  getEvents: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  event: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteEvent: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  deleteEvent,
  getEvents
})(FullEvent);
```

Comment: so once you get new data you need to update the lat and long points, is that what you are looking ?

Comment: Don't call async function inside a component's rendering cycle. Use `useEffect` for this.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I need DILEEP. I forgot to mention that I need what is console.log to got to ```<GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }}
          defaultCenter={ceneter}
          defaultZoom={13}
        >
          <Location lat={40.7263441} lng={-73.4364847} />
        </GoogleMapReact>```

Comment: Hey Emile, what you are telling me is too put the Geocode.fromAddress inside the UseEffect? After getEvents, I was doing it like that but I thought that was the reason I couldn’t pass the response to {center} (It says right now ceneter, it was a typo)

Comment: Not inside _the_ `useEffect`, inside **a** `useEffect`. Specifically, a new one which uses `location` as a dependency.

Comment: Would you show me, and how that will help me to get in the defaultCenter, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this (not testes, use as hint)

```
const FullEvent = ({ /* ... */ }) = {
  const [locationState, setLocationState] = useState({});
  // Get latidude & longitude from address.
  useEffect (() => {
    const getLocation = async () => { 
      const finalLocation = await Geocode.fromAddress({ location });
      setLocationState({ ...finalLocation.results[0].geometry.location });
    }
    await getLocation ();
  }, [location, setLocationState]);

  // And use
  <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{
        key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }}
      defaultCenter={{lat: 42.xxxxx, lng: -72.xxxx}}
      defaultZoom={13}
    >
      <Location lat={locationState.lat} lng={locationState.lng} />
    </GoogleMapReact>
```

Comment: This example does not work, the useEffect function should not be async and thus can not wait for getLocation. Remove await in front of getLocation in useEffect

Comment: Where does 'location' come from?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I will try the code. If you see the full code, location comes from the event props.

Comment: I get an error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I actually clean the async and await. It's true, doesn't work with that

Answer (score 0):

your answer was the solution and with the comment from Julian I was able to get what I wanted, I really appreciate it. The only thing I have to change is that instead of ({location}) I just wrote (location) and then got rid of the await before getLocation().

Below the changes, I made on the code to make it work

```
const FullEvent = ({ /* ... */ }) = {
  const [locationState, setLocationState] = useState({});
  // Get latidude & longitude from address.
  useEffect (() => {
    const getLocation = async () => { 
      const finalLocation = await Geocode.fromAddress(location);
      setLocationState({ ...finalLocation.results[0].geometry.location });
    }
    getLocation ();
  }, [location, setLocationState]);

  // And use
  <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{
        key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }}
      center={{lat: locationState.lat, lng: locationState.lng}}
      defaultZoom={13}
    >
      <Location lat={locationState.lat} lng={locationState.lng} />
    </GoogleMapReact>
```

And instead of defaultCenter, use center only so you won't get an error when you change to another event.